# AngularJS $q.all not waiting for all promises to resolve

Tags: angularjs, q

The below code is designed to recursively retrieve files from folders. $q.all(docDefs) is resolving when the first promise is resolved, even though the docDefs array shows multiple unresolved promises (the first promise shows a status of 1, while all others in array show a status of 0).

```
var getDocsAndFolders = function(siteUrl, rootFolderUrl) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var documents = [];
    var folders = [];
    var docDefs = [];
    var getDocs = function(folder) {
        var def = $q.defer();
        folders.push(folder);
        $q.all([getDocuments(siteUrl, folder.ServerRelativeUrl), getFolders(siteUrl, folder.ServerRelativeUrl)])
            .then(function(d) {
                documents = documents.concat(d[0].data.d.results);
                angular.forEach(d[1].data.d.Folders.results, function(rf) {
                    if (rf.ServerRelativeUrl.toLowerCase() != (rootFolderUrl + '/Forms')
                        .toLowerCase()) docDefs.push(getDocs(rf));
                });
                def.resolve();
            });
        return def.promise;
    };
    docDefs.push(getDocs({
        Name: 'Library',
        ServerRelativeUrl: rootFolderUrl
    }));
    $q.all(docDefs)
        .then(function() {
            deferred.resolve({
                documents: documents,
                folders: folders
            });
        });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: what do you have in docDefs before doing the $q.all() ? can you show ?

Comment: what is  `getDocuments()` & `getFolders()` method?

Comment: are getDocuments and getFolders promises ? if not, then this is your issue. Transofrm them into promises.

Comment: Yes, they both return promises returning $http.get . docDefs is an empty array to start.

Comment: Your docDefs array contains a single promise: I only see one instance of docDefs.push(). So it's quite normal that it's resolved when the first (and only) promise is resolved.

Comment: no, there is another docDefs.push() within my angular.forEach statement conditionally: docDefs.push(getDocs(rf));

Comment: This adds a promise to the docDefs array **after** $q.all(docDefs) is called.